# SSRS Tablix Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

The business has asked for columns in a tablix to be re-arranged but to keep their grouping.

Currently the report looks like:

[image: current]
it's grouped by 'Departing' and 'Destination' which both span over the 2 rows.

The business wants to keep the same grouping and data but re-arrange the columns to be

[image: future]

Is this possible? If I move the columns around to this order the grouping stops the 2nd row in the 'order part' column from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move existing columns around in SSRS 2005. Assuming that your COL1 and COL2 values  are in the group header row, you could do the following:

1. Right-click on COL2 > Split Cells
2. Right-click on COL1 > Split Cells
3. Right-click on COL1 > Insert Columns > Left
4. Set header/value of the newly inserted column to COL3
5. Leave detail row for COL2 and COL1 blank.
6. Lastly, you'll need to delete the old COL3

Comment: I'm a little bit confused and maybe wasn't clear in my question. I'm in the report designer (Visual Studio) and I don't get a split option when right clicking. The data in the question is just showing the data rows, not the header rows. Data is grouped by Col1 and Col2

Comment: Ok, so it's grouped by COL1 and COL2, but does the group have a header row or there is only a tablix header? Your chart seemed to imply  that you have a group header.  If not, you should be able to delete the COL1 and COL2 while leaving the grouping intact, insert two columns to the right of COL3 and then not show anything in the detail for those two columns.

Comment: I've updated the question with some pictures I've moked up of the actual report and what we're trying to do to it.

Comment: I see what you're trying to achieve. I don't think you can have a  detail column to the left of the group column in a Table control. However, you could achieve the same effect by deleting your group columns while maintaining grouping, adding two columns to the right of COL3, setting their fields to be COL1 and COL2.  Finally, using an expression for the TexBox visibility property of COL1 and COL2 to be something like: =RowNumber("COL1") <>  1

Comment: @alkos333 Can you put that in your answer and expand it a little? I'm not sure I understand completely.